# Valgrind memory leak for Detached thread

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads, posix

I am creating thread in following way:

```
for (i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++)
         Pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread, NULL);
```

In thread:

```
void *thread(void *vargp){
    Pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    //thread completes a job
 }
```

I am creating these detached Pthreads. However, Valgrind shows following error:

```
==38831== 2,240 bytes in 4 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 1 of 1
==38831==    at 0x4C2B974: calloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==38831==    by 0x4011DE4: _dl_allocate_tls (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
==38831==    by 0x503F960: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so)
==38831==    by 0x402BBD: main (server.c:54)
```

I saw a few posts here on SO about the same issue, but the suggestion there is to detach thread. I am already doing that. The approach here is that I create a pool of worker threads(in the first snippet) and use them to perform certain tasks. But before that I am calling Pthread_detach.
What's wrong here?

**Note** Captial letter before function is intentional. These are wrappers with error check included. Nothing fancy.

Comment: Are you creating all the threads with the same `pthread_t`?

Comment: The code you posted is line 54 in server.c?

Comment: It is difficult to find something missing (causing the leak) in such a short amount of code.

Comment: @e0k Yes. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Why does @Holsety know more about your code than the rest of us?

Comment: @Neo it could be, but it's not a lock.  Need more code/data.

Comment: @Martin James I just want to confirm it. Since there are wrapper functions, maybe the code posted is not the code with the problem.

Comment: @Holsety Wrapper just checks return value and prints error if any. Nothing fancy. There is nothing more that i am doing with the thread. Really. But I will see if there is any other relevant snippet that I should post.

Comment: The code posted is woefully inadequate to form any opinion on where there might be a leak.  For instance, it's supposedly creating a threadpool, but I don't see where the threads get their input queue, (or whatever it is they use to get work) from.

Comment: There is a queue(properly locked with mutex in critical section) from where the thread extracts the 'job'. And executes it. It is executing everything perfectly, except I don't how it is not reaping properly.